# How to select only part of image on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a star rating system for a website.  I'd like to select 0 1/2 or full stars.

For a SINGLE star click, what I want to achieve is this, and I'm not sure if it is something that can be done in `JavaScript` of `jQuery`:

If user clicks anywhere one the left half, it chooses 1/2 star; but on the right half, FULL star.   Of course, half's (ideally) would be divided right down the middle - 50/50 of area space.

Is this something that can be done?

Comment: try the jQuery raty plugin http://wbotelhos.com/raty#half

Comment: You could have each half be a separate image. Since you (probably) want to "fill" the halves anyway, this would make it easier - just swap out the empty star half image for a full star half image.

Comment: Pretend it's 1999: Imagemap.

Comment: @Diodeus  That's pretty funny actually; completely forgot about this concept.  Rather not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easier is always to have **2 images per start**, the left and right image, and a non-selected image that will serve as background if nothing is chosen.

you can easily develop a simple framework to make it **reusable throughout your website** (and future projects) but **I do wonder**, do you really want to do something that dozens of other open source projects already do?

as an **example**, check this **[RateIt](http://rateit.codeplex.com/)** plugin examples:

> http://www.radioactivethinking.com/rateit/example/example.htm

it includes all you need plus, all the extra nice ajax calls and several others settings that makes this really easy to use.

Comment: Marking you correct because if I build on my own; I'll do it this way.  But I think you are right, I'll see if there is a library that is suitable first.